# Get SOAP Message dynamically from asmx/wsdl

Tags: c#, soap, asmx, message

How can I get or create a SOAP Message dynamically if I am able to generate the proxy for the passed service url in c#?

1. I have a webpage with a textbox, user enters am asmx service url.
2. I have a code that dynamically generates the proxy. Used the code from 
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/39138d08-aa08-4c0c-9a58-0eb81a672f54
   Although, I have to figure out how can I determine the namespace/service name dynamically for the selected service.
3. I get the list of all methods for the service in dropdown.
4. Now when user selects a method, I want to show the Soap Message like the following in a textarea:

`

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetIncomeReport xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <RequestContext xmlns="">
        <userid>string</userid>
        <fcnumber>string</fcnumber>
        <wirecall>string</wirecall>
        <officeprefix>string</officeprefix>
        <accountaccess>string</accountaccess>
      </RequestContext>
      <ReportParams>string</ReportParams>
    </GetIncomeReport>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

`

Comment: The only way to see the XML is to use a SoapExtension. This is much easier if you use WCF (a Service Reference). Is there a reason why not to use WCF?

Comment: john, I would have loved to use WCF but unfortunately these services already exist in production and moreover they are supported by a different group of people in the organization. May be in future they will convert asmx to wcf but not now :(. Appreiate if you can point me to SoapExtension examples otherwise I may need to build by my own.

Comment: I mean that if you use "Add Service Reference" against the existing services, then you'll get the ability to see the XML almost for free. The services won't have to change at all.

Comment: See [SoapExtension class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx).

Comment: John, by any chance you can answer the comment on point 2 in my question? How can I determine the namespace and service name dynamically for the selected service.

Comment: Sorry, no, I've never needed to do this.

Comment: did you get final solution ?